# Better MonoTouch crashes with TestFlight

Tags: c#, iphone, ios, xamarin.ios, testflight

We've hooked up TestFlight and the TestFlight SDK with MonoTouch and so far it's working great.

One thing we've noticed is that the crash reports are more geared towards Obj-C apps.

They look like this after you upload a zipped dSYM file:

```
0 OurApp 0x007a7116 testflight_backtrace + 170
1 OurApp0x007a7c3c TFSignalHandler + 208
2 libsystem_c.dylib 0x34f68538 _sigtramp + 48
3 libsystem_c.dylib 0x34f5df5a pthread_kill + 54
4 libsystem_c.dylib 0x34f56fea abort + 94
5 OurApp 0x007793b3 monoeg_g_logv (goutput.c:137)
6 OurApp 0x0077941f monoeg_g_log (goutput.c:147)
7 OurApp 0x005f1393 get_numerous_trampoline (aot-runtime.c:3447)
8 OurApp 0x005f1b2f mono_aot_get_imt_thunk (aot-runtime.c:3576)
9 OurApp 0x006e2c83 initialize_imt_slot (object.c:1247)
10 OurApp 0x006e321f build_imt_slots (object.c:1371)
11 OurApp 0x006e356f mono_vtable_build_imt_slot (object.c:1439)
12 OurApp 0x005fcf83 mono_convert_imt_slot_to_vtable_slot (mini-trampolines.c:198)
13 OurApp 0x005fd50f common_call_trampoline (mini-trampolines.c:333)
14 OurApp 0x005fe573 mono_vcall_trampoline (mini-trampolines.c:644)
15 OurApp 0x0056a68f generic_trampoline_vcall (mscorlib.dll.6.s:194345)
16 OurApp 0x00416b4f System_Collections_Generic_List_1__ctor_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_1_T (mscorlib.dll.6.s:32014)
17 OurApp 0x0026955b System_Linq_Enumerable_ToList_TSource_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_1_TSource (System.Core.dll.6.s:1917)
```

So you can tell the general C# function where the crash occurred.  (Note: this crash was a bug in MonoTouch 5.0.1 where Linq generics were messed up, seems to be fixed in 5.0.2)

It would be nice to get the full C# stack trace in here, any thoughts on how to do that?  I could hook into `AppDomain.UnhandledException` and put a try-catch around my `static void Main` method, but wondered if there is a way to report the stack trace out to TestFlight.

Comment: a small note to confirm that 5.0.1 had a regression (i.e. 5.0 was fine) which causes `EngineExecutionException` to be thrown in some cases. This was fixed in 5.0.2.

Comment: I have been exploring this problem too and I haven't come up with anything. (I would settle for just the line number to be honest.)

Comment: I was thinking about trying to send full exception details as a checkpoint (even though that's not what it's for).  I'm not sure how it will look on TestFlight, though.

Comment: Note: putting a stacktrace through a checkpoint looks horrendous, wouldn't recommend it as a solution.

Comment: I believe you can set a custom exception handler, which the TestFlight SDK demonstrates how to do. You could probably retrieve your function stack trace thingy there and send it to TestFlight using a feedback controller or something.

Comment: These crashes usually mean the app quits (so no chance to show a feedback controller).  Can you post a link to the custom exception handler doc you mention?  Only think I found was a fork on GitHub here: https://github.com/danielctull/TestFlight-SDK

Comment: Did the latest release correct this? http://support.testflightapp.com/discussions/sdk/37-no-line-numbers-in-stacktrace

Comment: Yeah, I was using the latest version mentioned on that discussion, I uploaded a dSym file which produced the output above in my question.  My issue is due to us using MonoTouch and wanting to see C#-style stacktraces, which we can produce ourselves and report--there is just not a way we know how to pass a custom stack trace to TestFlight.

Comment: I read this as 'I want MonoTouch to crash more effectively'. ;)

Comment: We had the same problem and ended up going for the try/catch around `Main` statement, dumping the C# stack traces to a log file and sending that to our server.

Comment: This is an old question - but for anyone searching, we've had very good luck with Raygun.io in our Monotouch applications. It collects a much better and complete stack trace.

Comment: @Ender2050, we use it too. Agreed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with MonoTouch, but what about using the [Remote Logging](https://testflightapp.com/sdk/doc/0.8.2/) features of the TestFlight SDK?

Comment: I was using MonoTouch binding here: https://github.com/ayoung/monotouch-testflight  Which I don't know if he has the TFlog Obj-C function setup for use from C#.  I will try to bind all missing methods myself and see if any of them solve this issue.

Comment: Found a newer one (commit on Feb 01) here: https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/tree/master/TestFlight  Going to try it.

Comment: Ok, using `TestFlight.Log()` works pretty well.  You have to log exceptions in `AppDomain.UnhandledException` and in `static void Main()`.  The C# stacktrace won't show up as a crash report, but you can view it in the log of the session.

Comment: What are you sending to TestFlight.Log?